# Issue with hierarchical logistic regression in pymc3

Tags: python, statistics, pymc3

I'm trying to build a hierarchical logistic regression with pymc3, but appear to be having some kind of convergence or misspecification issues, as the trace output only generates a single value for each parameter and runs through 2000 samples in 10 seconds.

Here is the model, which has 6 groups and varying slopes/intercept:

```
def invlogit(x):
    return np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x))

with Model() as logistic_reg:

    # Priors
    mu_a = Normal('mu_a', mu=0., sd=100)
    sigma_a = Uniform('sigma_a', 0, 50)
    mu_b = Normal('mu_b' , mu=0., sd=100)
    sigma_b = Uniform('sigma_b', 0, 50)
    mu_b_2 = Normal('mu_b_2', mu=0., sd=100)
    sigma_b_2 = Uniform('sigma_b_2', 0, 50)
    mu_b_3 = Normal('mu_b_3', mu=0., sd=100)
    sigma_b_3 = Uniform('sigma_b_3', 0, 50)

    # Random intercepts
    a = Normal('a', mu=mu_a, sd=sigma_a, shape=group_n)
    # Random slopes
    b = Normal('b', mu=mu_b, sd=sigma_b, shape=group_n)
    b2 = Normal('b2', mu=mu_b_2, sd=sigma_b_2, shape=group_n)
    b3 = Normal('b3', mu=mu_b_3, sd=sigma_b_3, shape=group_n)


    # Expected value
    p = invlogit(a[group] + b[group] * norm_score + b2[group] * nine_dummy + b3[group] * nine_dummy * norm_score)

    #Likelihood
    y_obs = pm.Bernoulli('y_obs', p=p, observed=outcome)

with logistic_reg:
    niter = 2000
    start = pm.find_MAP()
    step = pm.NUTS()
    trace = pm.sample(niter, step, start, progressbar=True)
```

The above runs without exceptions, but the trace shows unchanging values throughout the 2k samples taken for each parameter.

However, when I run the same model without the hierarchical priors, it seems to run the unpooled model as expected, without any issues:

```
def invlogit(x):
    return np.exp(x) / (1 + np.exp(x))

with Model() as logistic_reg:

    # Random intercepts
    a = Normal('a', mu=0, sd=100, shape=group_n)
    # Random slopes
    b = Normal('b', mu=0, sd=100, shape=group_n)
    b2 = Normal('b2', mu=0, sd=100, shape=group_n)
    b3 = Normal('b3', mu=0, sd=100, shape=group_n)


    # Expected value
    p = invlogit(a[group] + b[group] * norm_score + b2[group] * nine_dummy + b3[group] * nine_dummy * norm_score)

    #Likelihood
    y_obs = pm.Bernoulli('y_obs', p=p, observed=outcome)

with logistic_reg:
        niter = 2000
        start = pm.find_MAP()
        step = pm.NUTS()
        trace = pm.sample(niter, step, start, progressbar=True)
```

[image]

Given that the non-pooled model seems to work fine, I'm convinced I'm somehow mis-specifying my priors in the partially pooled one, though I can't figure out how.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try using Metropolis instead of NUTS? (probably without ```find_MAP()```)

Comment: You may also try replacing the Uniform distributions by HalfCauchy distributions, something like ```sigma_a = pm.HalfCauchy('sigma_a', 100)``` (With NUTS or Metropolis).

Comment: @aloctavodia: It seems as though you were correct and that NUTS was the source of my issues - even with the halfcauchy, NUTS would get stuck around the 200th sample.  On an unrelated note, I'm a big fan of your Doing_bayesian_data_analysis github repository - thank you for doing what you do!

Comment: Glad it works and also glad you find the DBDA repository useful. Thanks.